# Can't hang out with Amanda after game completion

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

As Michael, I can call Amanda and select the option to hang out with her. Sometimes, she agrees. But after that, I can't seem to find her anywhere. She's not anywhere at home, and there's no blip on the map directing me to where I should pick her up.

Is this a bug, or is there some place I'm supposed to automatically know she'll be?

Comment: I'm afraid to ask, but did Amanda leave you for a questionable Yoga teacher per chance?

Comment: @Nolonar Yes, but he's been taken care of.

Comment: She leaves Michael for Trevor because Michael's boring and she wants a real man.